# Add different CSS Classes to multiple H2s

Tags: javascript

I have multiple `<h2>` Tags on my HTML (dynamically generated) and want to add by Javascript or jQuery to every `<h2>` a unique class like `<h2 class="h2-1">`, `<h2 class="h2-2">`, `<h2 class="h2-3">`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried this yourself? And what's the purpose of a unique class name, given that a class is often used to group similarly styled elements together for easier selection via CSS?

Comment: Why can't you just add them on the generation?

Comment: Also, if they need to be unique then id's would be a better approach. Add the id in the loop that echoes it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('h2').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass("h2-" + index);
})
```

Comment: Works great. How can i now select one of these? Like
???.('h2-1').insertAdjacentHTML ....

Comment: You can use: `$('h2-1')[0].insertAdjacentHTML`

Comment: Cause i want to add content after or before the 2nd h2-Tag like i did here with getelementbyid:

document.getElementById('h2-1').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="AdMediumRectangle">Here comes the content</div>

Comment: in that case use: `$('h2-1').after('<div></div>')`

Comment: Hmmm.not working and no console output. I have 

 jQuery('h2').each(function(index){
  jQuery(this).addClass("h2-" + index);
 })

 jQuery('h2-1').after().append('<div class="AdMediumRectangle">Content...</div>');

Comment: excuse me i have mistake you must use: `$('h2-1').after('<div></div>')`

Comment: Must be Query('.h2-1').after().append( ...
in my case. Thanks a lot. Works now! The dot was missing ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `each` function to find all `h2` tags on your page and have index to add unique identifier to each in this sequence.

Try code below.

```js
$('h2').each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).addClass('h2_' + i);
});
```

```css
.h2_0 { color: red }
.h2_1 { color: green }
.h2_2 { color: yellow }
.h2_3 { color: orange }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>1</h2>
<h2>2</h2>
<h2>3</h2>
<h2>4</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously not very familiar with javascript, jquery?

```
for(var i = 0, i < $("h2").length, i++) {
  $("h2")[i].addClass("h2-" + i);
}
```

Comment: Not really. PHP is more familiar to me...thanks